# error in using DTDparser

Tags: java, dtd-parsing

I have written a code to parse a DTD file using DTDParser jar.the code is

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.dtd"));
DTDParser dtd=new DTDParser(bff);
DTD dt=dtd.Parse();
System.out.println(dt.elements);
}
```

and output i get is

message=com.wutka.DTDElement@c20e24...etc same as this for all elements with with diff @no changes..
But i need just the element names...
also help me in putting those values in an array so i can use it for further vlidation...thank u..

Answer (score 0):

If you want elements in an array or preferably a list then you need to iterate over `dt.elements` such as:

```
List<String> elementNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (DTDElement element : dt.elements)
{
    elementNames.add(element.getName());
}
```

I am not aware of the specifics of this library (i.e. getName() method might not exist) but that is a general concept.

Comment: thank u...but another main problem is getting '=com.wutka....' in output after every element name!!!